# Gantt chart data visualization

Tags: c#, mysql, gantt-chart

I have a c# windows form application that controls the data in a MySQL database. This is the back end but I would like to display the DB info on a Gantt chart that will be displayed for the employees in a production environment. The back end works perfectly but I don't know where to start with the Gantt chart. When searching for info, I found a whole bunch of solution ($$) but they also include the backend. I'm looking for a simple free chart that will feed of the DB info. So basically I'm just looking for the interface. I don't mind building it myself but I don't know where to start. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A good starting point is [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mschart+gantt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b). Example with [MSChart](https://forums.asp.net/t/1641874.aspx?Can%2Bwe%2Bcreate%2BGANTT%2Bcharts%2Busing%2BMS%2BChart%2BControls%2B)..

Comment: Thank you. I found that already. Like I said in the question, I did Google this already. What I’m looking for is more recent examples or references that other devs might of used. The link you provided is good but is quite old.

Comment: Well, the next thing is to describe your data and your requirements. A StackedBar or a RangeBar chart is the usual solution. With a clear data interface writing up an example should be rather simple.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339148/chart-does-not-read-correctly-seconds-from-datetime-variable-c-sharp) is an explanation of how to set the values to create a RangeBar Gantt chart..