# How can I make a gantt chart in winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developping a project management application, I need to make a Gantt chart from tasks. Now I'm using  DlhSoft library but it's a trial version I need something free like google charts.

I hope you can help me,
kind regards!

Comment: Try a `ChartType.Range` chart as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558079/gantt-chart-data-visualization)

Comment: Thank you so much  @TaW